# Terminology-wise, how do I differentiate between a "percentage percentage" gain, and a "additive percentage" gain?

Tags: terminology, percentage

Sorry if the question title is confusing - I'll explain.

I often have to provide answers like "If we did X, than Y would be P% larger."  This is fine if the units of Y are "absolute units."  For example - "If the plant is given food twice a week instead of once, its expected height after 3 months is 12% higher."

However, I never know how to phrase it when the units of Y are already percentages.  For example, say I'm measuring how many people click on an ad.  Assume that currently, 30% of people click, but if we change the ad's wording, 42% of people click.

I could say that that is a 40% increase in click rate (because 42/30 = 1.4; this is my "percentage percentage" gain).  Or, I could say that it's a 12% increase in click rate (because 42% - 30% = 12%; this is my "additive percentage" gain).

At times, I'll want to give both values, but obviously this gets very confusing.  Is there correct terminology?  Concretely:

1. If I wanted to say that changing the ad wording causes a 12% increase, from X% to (X+12)%, how should I say that?
2. If I wanted to say that changing the ad wording causes a 40% increase, from X% to (1.4 * X)%, how should I say that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are describing Percentages (2) and Percentage points (1).

More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point).

Comment: In symbols it would be % vs %p.

Comment: Thank you!  This was driving me crazy.  I should have thought of that!